# How to improve performance with translate?

Tags: ionic3

I read a article about ionic performance improvements and I saw a topic that translate is better than margin, because it use the GPU that is faster than CPU to render. How can I use margin-right and padding with this animations?

For example:

Slower rendering:

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

Faster rendering:

```
transform: translate(10px, 0);
```

For `margin-right`, I tried with `translate3d`, but doesn't work (I tried in a `ion-row`).

So how can I use this kind of improvement with `padding` and `margin` (right and bottom)?

Beside that, do you guys have others tips to improve the ionic 3 performance?

Thanks!

Comment: hey Juny i dont think you will gain any meaningful performance boost with this. Best - build your full app and IF performance is slow - use Chrome dev tools to learn why and then only then optimize what exactly is causing slowness

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergey! Ok, I'll do that. But one problem that I'm having, is when click in an ion-card to push a page. In chrome is very fast, but in the device, takes about 2 seconds..

Comment: can you create new question specific to that issue and add the code you have plus detailed context for it (like do you see this on every click press or only first one, also if you are using lazy loading etc)